# Jenkins Build Statisitics Report tool/plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I need a tool/plugins for jenkins that takes a (file) list of project and reports their build status:

•   Time of last build.
•   Did build succeed or fail?
•   Time of last successful build.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

First result in the Google search
https://wiki.jenkins.io/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=46336030.